# Laravel job chaining

Tags: php, laravel, jobs, laravel-5.7

I have been tearing my hair out this afternoon attempting to get job chaining to work. No matter what happens I cannot get a chained job to run. The first always runs and succeeds but the chained will never run.

For example I have an event listener like

```
  class PersistPreviousStatement implements ShouldQueue
    {
        /**
         * @param StatementCreated $event
         */
        public function handle(StatementCreated $event): void
        {
            DoOneThing::withChain([
                new DoSomething()
            ])->dispatch();
        }
}
```

My two job classes are below:

```
class DoOneThing
{
    use Dispatchable, Queueable;

    public function handle(): void
    {
        $statement = Statement::find(20);
        $statement->file = 'yyy';
        $statement->save();
    }
}


class DoSomething
{
    use Dispatchable, Queueable;

    public function handle(): void
    {
        $statement = Statement::find(10);
        $statement->file = 'xxxx';
        $statement->save();
    }
}
```

In the situation above. My DoOneThing class correctly sets the record with 'yyy' however the DoSomething class does not run. If I change the order like

```
DoSomething::withChain([
            new DoOneThing()
        ])->dispatch();
```

DoSomething is ran not DoOnething. I have both jobs set to queueable/Dispatchable and my driver is set to sync. I also can dispatch the jobs after each other independently like:

DoSomething::dispatch()
DoOneThing::dispatch()

and both will run.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you not have to return true from the handle method for it to class as completed?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the InteractsWithQueue trait in my jobs.

Comment: I have same issue with your original post, but still not working after addding InteractsWithQueue

Comment: My mistake. I implements ShouldQueue on nested jobs. Once removed, the chains works.